# Apache mod-rewrite folder overwrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have Apache installed with the XAMPP package, and I'm working locally.

I have a rule in a .htaccess file that overwrites everything, let's take this for example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?x=$1
```

Note that I do NOT have any RewriteCond that makes this rule ignore existing file or folders.

Now let's say I have a folder named "mydir". When I go to **http://localhost/mydir/** it does indeed overwrite this and the contents of the folder are not shown. However, you know how usually when you open a folder in the browser, without the last slash, it is automatically added? Well it still does that, with a weird behavior. If I go to **http://localhost/mydir** it automatically changes the url to **http://localhost/mydir/?x=mydir**.

Well that's messed up, because it breaks my rule pretty bad. Is it some sort of Apache config setting, or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the reference to `DirectorySlash` on

```
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html
```